# Jest snapshots differ between local setup and CI when rendering mjml templates

Tags: jestjs, mjml

So I have mjml templates which I test after rendering them with the jests snapshot feature. Locally all is good but then in the CI pipe this weird error occurs:

```
    -           .mj-outlook-group-fix { width:100% !important; }
    +           .outlook-group-fix { width:100% !important; }
```

So the difference between the snapshots really only is that in the CI sometimes `mj-` is missing. Which is totally weird to me as the CI of course also has the exact same version of all dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out that my CI was running node version 13 while I was running version 12 locally. After aligning the versions the snapshots would be in sync. It still is very very odd though IMHO why class name creation would depend on the node version though.